# TensorFlow Hub error when Saving model as H5 or SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I want to use this TF Hub asset:
https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_50/feature_vector/3

Versions:

```
Version:  1.15.0-dev20190726
Eager mode:  False
Hub version:  0.5.0
GPU is available
```

Code

```
feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_50/feature_vector/3"
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(module,
                                         input_shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS))
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Importing a SavedModel with tf.saved_model.load requires a 'tags=' argument if there is more than one MetaGraph. Got 'tags=None', but there are 2 MetaGraphs in the SavedModel with tag sets [[], ['train']]. Pass a 'tags=' argument to load this SavedModel.
```

I tried:

```
module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_50/feature_vector/3",
                    tags={"train"})
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(module, 
                                         input_shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS))
```

But when I try to save the model I get:

```
tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, tf_model_path)
# model.save(h5_model_path) # Same error 

NotImplementedError: Can only generate a valid config for `hub.KerasLayer(handle, ...)`that uses a string `handle`.
Got `type(handle)`: <class 'tensorflow_hub.module.Module'>
```

Tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/hub_with_keras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but assuming you have migrated to the TF2, this can easily be accomplished with the most recent model version as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

num_classes=10 # For example
m = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_50/feature_vector/5", trainable=True)
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
m.build([None, 224, 224, 3])  # Batch input shape.

# train as needed

m.save("/some/output/path")
```

Please update this question if that doesn't work for you. I believe your issue arose from mixing `hub.Module` with `hub.KerasLayer`. The model version you were using was in TF1 Hub format, so within TF1 it is meant to be used exclusively with `hub.Module`, and not mixed with `hub.KerasLayer`. Within TF2, `hub.KerasLayer` can load TF1 Hub format models directly from their URL for composition in larger models, but they cannot be fine-tuned.

Please refer to [this compatibility guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/model_compatibility) for more information

Comment: Thanks Morgan, I haven't used this in a while, but may have time next week.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `tf.keras.models.save_model(model,'NeuralNetworkModel')`
You will get saved model in a folder that can be used later in your sequential nework