# How to save a model in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I am using pertained weights for an image classification task. I am using Tensorflow version 1.14.0, I am using mobilenetv1_050_224 for this task from the following [source](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v1_050_224/classification/3).

```
IMAGE_SHAPE = (400, 400)
n_classes = 10
classifier_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v1_050_224/classification/3'
base_model = hub.Module(classifier_url, tags=['train'])
base_model.trainable = False
classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(base_model, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')
])
#print (base_model.summary())
print (classifier.summary())
```

I train this model and I am able to get a good train/validation accuracy on my dataset using transfer learning. The following is the code for learning part.

```
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1./255)

validation_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
    x = train_dataset,
    y = train_labels,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=1)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow(
    x = validation_dataset, # Source directory for the validation images
    y = valid_labels,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=1)

classifier.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs = 2
steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n // batch_size
validation_steps = validation_generator.n // batch_size

model = classifier.fit_generator(train_generator,
                                 steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
                                 epochs=epochs,
                                 workers=4,
                                 validation_data=validation_generator,
                                 validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

However when I try to save the model:

```
export_path = '/tmp/simple_keras_model.h5'
classifier.save(export_path, save_format='h5')
```

I'm getting the following error:

> NotImplementedError: Can only generate a valid config for
>   `hub.KerasLayer(handle, ...)`that uses a string `handle`.
>
> Got `type(handle)`:

I am stuck on it and unable to get my head around it. Any leads in this regard would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you remove the \tmp\ part from the path, just use `simple_keras_model.h5` and try to save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `classifier` by

```
# save the underlying  tensorflow graph
model_file = classifier.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as source:
    source.write(model_file)
# save model parameter 
classifier.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

Then the saved model can be loaded by

```
from keras.models import model_from_json

with open("model.json", "r") as f:
    classifier = model_from_json(f.read())
classifier.load_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

Comment: I am getting the same above error at this line : model_file = classifier.to_json()

Comment: sorry I thought it was the way of saving the model causes the problem. I'm not familiar with `hub`, I guess the problem is `classifier` is not constructed properly by `hub`.

Comment: I think I know the problem. The thing is I am using hub.keraslayer() with a hub module like hub.load(classifier_url). However it says in documentation that :      handle: a callable object (subject to the conventions above), or a Python string for which hub.load() returns such a callable. A string is required to save the Keras config of this Layer. so inorder to save the model I need to pass string to hub.keraslayer() not hub module.

Comment: I found an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/343) reporting the same problem you encounter, and also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57229641)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
# Export the model to a SavedModel
keras.experimental.export_saved_model(classifier, '/tmp/simple_keras_model.h5')

# Recreate the exact same model
new_model = keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model('/tmp/simple_keras_model.h5')
```

[Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/saving_and_serializing#export_to_savedmodel)

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/343), only TF2-compatible Hub modules work with hub.Keras.

But can use SavedModel to save it. Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/saved_model.ipynb) on how to use SavedModel API